# Can you find the exact function after differentiating it, and then antidifferentiating it?

Tags: calculus

Given that

$$
\rho = \frac{\delta\psi}{\delta r}\\  \int_{a}^{b} \psi \space\delta r = 1
$$

Is the following mathematically accurate?

$$\psi = \int \rho \space\delta r - c \\  c = \frac{1-\int_{a}^{b}(\psi + c) \space\delta r}{b-a} \\  c = \frac{1- \int_{a}^{b}(\int \rho \space\delta r)\space\delta r}{b-a} \\  \psi = \int \rho \space\delta r - (\frac{1- \int_{a}^{b}(\int \rho \space\delta r) \space\delta r}{b-a})
$$

Comment: I'm assuming c is a constant that comes from integration?

Comment: @Enzo Yes, it is

Comment: Well the problem lies in
$\psi = \int\rho\ \delta r + c$ because to get the exact $\psi$ back you need to specify a region over which you are integrating $\rho$ with. The relationship between $\psi$ and $\rho$ is more than simply an anti-derivative. You need to give the correct initial condition to solve for $\psi$ in the equation $\rho = \dfrac{\delta \psi}{\delta r}$

Comment: @Enzo I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you explain? How is it not an antiderivative?

Answer (score 1):

Please do not write functions in terms of indefinite integrals, it will only lead to confusion.

What is true is that

$$\psi(r) = \int_c^r \rho(s)\, ds - \psi(c)$$
$$\psi(c) = \frac{1-\int_a^b (\psi(r)-\psi(c))\,dr}{b-a}$$
$$\psi(c) = \frac{1-\int_a^b \int_c^r \rho(s)\,ds\,dr}{b-a}$$
$$\psi(r) = \int_c^r \rho(s)\, ds - \frac{1-\int_a^b \int_c^t \rho(s)\,ds\,dt}{b-a}.$$

Comment: Why can't I write a function as an indefinite integral?

Comment: What is $g(y) = \int x\,dx$ as a function of $y$? It is nonsense when separated from its limits of integration. With $g(y) = \int_c^y x\,dx$ there is no possible confusion.

Comment: I was under the impression that anti-differentiating a derivative of a function gives the function + a constant. Is this incorrect?

Comment: If by $\int_{c}^{y} x \space dx$ you're saying I should be using a definite integral there, I don't see why. It's not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: That is correct, but the constant is not arbitrary, it depends on the limits you chose when you antidifferentiated, and vice verse.

Comment: But if I don't set limits, and the domain of $\psi$ can be anything, how does it make sense to use limits at all?

Comment: In other words, the indefinite integral $\int x\, dx$ is not a well-defined function. It could be $x^2/2$. It could be $x^2/2+42$. If you can abuse notation and still get the right answer, go ahead, but you do so at your own risk :)

Comment: The point of the next steps is to find the constant that is added to it. If it happens to contain the meaning of life, the second last equation should solve to it. Also, remember that we know the definite integral is 1

Comment: I just need to know if my math is correct for now, I can figure out how to make it look better after I know I'm not just wasting my time.

Comment: Provided the right term is interpreted correctly, yes.

Comment: Great, thanks. :)